# Draw a UIImage right after a multi-line NSString or NSAttributedString in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uiimage, nsattributedstring

Please see image below. I need to show heart symbol (that I have as a png) right after the text with one space. It may be simple in single line text but in multi-line case (as shown below) how can I manage this? Please note that these are UITableViewCells and I am using UILabel for text.

If I use Emoji character (♥) it always displays in Red on iPhone which doesn't match the required color. So what's the solution? Is there some other character code that can be used? If not how will I know the ending x,y position of text so that I place png there?

[image]

Comment: this might help you. Instead of UILabel you can use UIWebView.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057960/images-inside-of-uilabel

Answer (score 0):

You can append the append the unicode value for your emoji character to the string :

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",yourLabelText,@"\U0001F431"];
```

find  unicode value for your emoji character from :

http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode
or   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji

Comment: He said in his question he doesn't want to use the emoji because of the color.

Comment: Yes, this is not the solution. :(